# What about the selfadjointness of this operator?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $H$ be an Hilbert space and let $T:H\longrightarrow H$ be a bounded operator which is also an isomorphism. Let $H_0\hookrightarrow H$ be a Hilbert space embedded in $H$ and consider the operator $A$ defined as the restriction of $T$ to $H_0$. Suppose that $A$ is self-adjoint on $H_0$. It is sufficient to conclude that $T$ is self-adjoint?

Looking at the comments in previous question, it seems to be false. So, there are any which $H_0$ should verify in order to have the self-adjointness for $T$?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean when you say that the unbounded operator is an "isomorphism"? Are you just saying that the operator is bijective?

Comment: I mean that $T$ is a bicontinuous linear map.

Comment: You said that $T$ is unbounded, now you're saying that it's continuous. Which one is it?

Comment: Is $H_0$ dense?

Comment: @C.B If $T$ is continuous, then it must be bounded. If an operator fails to be bounded, it cannot be an isomorphism of Hilbert spaces.

Comment: There is  a mistake in my question, I mean "bounded". I edit immediately and if anyone could help me again, I'lle really grateful.

Comment: @C.B If $H_0 \subseteq H$ is a Hilbert space, then it is impossible to deduce the self-adjointness of $T$ from the self-adjointess of the restricition $T|_{H_0}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a little confusing, so hopefully this helps.

Let $T:H\rightarrow H$ be unbounded with domain $H_0$. If $H_0$ is dense and $T$ is symmetric, then the following three are equivalent, in general:

1. $T$ is self-adjoint.
2. $T$ is closed, and $\ker (T^*\pm i)=0$.
3. $\mathcal{R}(T\pm i)=H.$

EDIT: If $T$ is bounded, then a sufficient condition is that $H_0$ is a dense subspace, although this does not depend on the invertibility of $T$.

Comment: Where could I use the fact that $T$ is an isomorphism in this result?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you mean by unbounded isomorphism of Hilbert spaces, so I gave a general result for unbounded operators.